# Doubt about seed setting

Tags: r

I'm doing some data analysis using R and I wrote `set.seed(100)` at the top of my code.
My question is: can I set a random value for the seed? Is there a meaning for a specific value of the seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed ensure that you can reproduce results. This becomes very important when you want to show results to client.

Specific values of seed should not matter in most cases. But in some cases starting at some seed may give you worse results then other in that case you should try multiple seed values

Comment: ok thanks! There is a procedure to find the best values or I just test random value and verify the result?

Comment: its random test and verify the results..

Answer (score 0):

You generally use a seed to make sure that the result is the same each time you run your code/script. The specific value for the seed doesn't matter as it shouldn't change your results significantly and doesn't have any impact on the reproducibility of your results.